# Does the call $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser() pull data from AD or SP User Profiles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010

I am currently debugging a Sharepoint 2010 website and hitting an error when the debugger hits the following function:

```
var thisUserID = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "ID",
    debug: false
});
```

The error is:

```
The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object
```

So I am wondering ([as a user at the bottom did too](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser)) does the call $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser() pull data from AD or SP User Profiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know it pulls information from Active Directory and not User Profiles, I have tried and tested it. It does act weird at times thought.